# Latex: description list [style=nextline] doesn't work as expected when enclosing an enumerated list

Tags: latex

I am trying to do the following:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item [First Thing]
  \item [Second Thing]
  \item [Third Thing] 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Ite,
  \end{enumerate}
  \item [Final Thing]
\end{description}
```

However, the enumerated list starts on the same line as the description, not on the next line as I would like. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this nicely? I tried adding a \hfill after [Third Thing], and this sorts of works, but leaves too large a vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add anything after "third thing", in order to have the enumerate on another line. And the simplest is an empty box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item [First Thing]
  \item [Second Thing]
  \item [Third Thing]    \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Ite,
    \end{enumerate}
  \item [Final Thing]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is probably what you consider a "too large vertical space", but this is the behaviour of nextline style. Without it, lines are much closer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}%[style=nextline]
  \item [First Thing]
  \item [Second Thing]
  \item [Third Thing]    \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item,
    \end{enumerate}
  \item [Final Thing]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, if you want a large space everywhere, but after third thing, you can hand control the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item [First Thing]
  \item [Second Thing]
  \item [Third Thing]    \mbox{}\\[-1cm]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item,
    \end{enumerate}
  \item [Final Thing]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]